# cannot get processing script to run

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm doing a Processing.js tutorial found here:http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html

When I load my document into the browser I get two errors:

```
uncaught exception: called Processing constructor without passing canvas element reference or id.
```

And

```
Access to restricted URI denied

xhr.send(null)
```

In regard to the first error, I pass the canvas element id like so:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
```

I also checked and made sure that the canvas element in the HTML had the `canvas1` id.

I'm not sure what went wrong with the second error.

Please help me see what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
function sketchProc(processing) {
        processing.draw = function() {
            var centerX = processing.width / 2; 
            var centerY = processing.height / 2;
            var maxArmLength = Math.min(centerX, centerY);

            function drawArm(position, lengthScale, weight) {
                processing.strokeWeight(weight);
                processing.line(centerX, centerY, 
                    centerX + Math.sin(position * 2 * Math.PI) * lengthScale * maxArmLength,
                    centerY - Math.cos(position * 2 * Math.PI) * lengthScale * maxArmLength);
            }

            processing.background(224);

            var now = new Date();

            var hoursPosition = (now.getHours() % 12 + now.getMinutes() / 60) / 12;
            drawArm(hoursPosition, 0.5, 5);
        }
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

    var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

Comment: Where is that code that initializes the Processing object?  Is it in a `<script>` block in the `<head>`, before the `<body>` perhaps?  If so, then that call to "getElementById()" won't find anything because the DOM will not have been built yet.

Comment: @Pointy--placing the code at the bottom of the page helped. But I don't like structuring my code this way. Is there a way to call the processing.js code externally? or place it at the top?

Comment: Yes, it would help to put it in an "onload" handler or, alternatively, at the *end* of the `<body>`.  If you're getting a syntax error, that means, well, that there's a syntax error :-)

Comment: @Pointy--How can i keep all of the script tags at the top of the page and still execute the processing.js code? the `onload` handler does not seem to work. Placing the code at the bottom of the document does work, but this is a last resort.

Comment: Putting it in an "onload" handler will work if it's done properly.  Putting scripts at the end of the `<body>` is not a bad thing and is in fact a practice recommended by many knowledgeable people in the JavaScript world.

Comment: @Pointy--any special reason why this is the recommended practice?

Comment: Mostly it's for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

"Access to restricted URI denied" suggests you were loading it from file:///, which means you can't do XHR file loading in any modern browser. You'll have to either run it from a localhost server (be that using Apache or a simple Python or PHP one-liner), or you'll have to put your files online in order to run your sketch.

Also, remember to verify that your "canvas" variable actually has any content. Running a script in the <head> before DOMContentLoaded means any document.getElementById will fail: your code will trigger before <body> has been built up. Either run your script at the end of the body, or (better) stick all your code inside a function and call that function as

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",myfunction,false):
```

making sure to add an extra line as first line in your function:

```
function myfunction() {
  document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",myfunction,false);
  [...]
```

Or, if you use frameworks like prototype, dojo, jquery, whatever, you can use their construct for executing JS only after the page has been built up.